# Why jsonschema is not match with the json?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Given that, I have the below json:

```
{
"msg":"aaaa",
"email":"aaa@gmail.com"
}
```

Then, I wrote the below json schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Json schema sample",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": true,
  "required": [
    "msg",
    "email"
  ],

  "properties": {
    "msg": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$"
    }
  }
}
```

And sadly it is not matches with the json.

If you remove the `,"pattern": "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$"` which is the regular expression for checking the `email`, then it works well. [Please test it in this website](https://jsonschemalint.com/#!/version/draft-07/markup/json).

I am sure that my regular expression for email is fine. But I don't know why it is not working in the json schema!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\` is also an escape character in the json string, so now it's invalid json.
You could also see that when validating the json, for example on [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/)

[image]

So your pattern needs a second `\`:

```
pattern": "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,}$"
```

Full example: (don't forget to select draft-04 on https://jsonschemalint.com/, or change the schema to draft-07)

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Json schema sample",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": true,
  "required": [
    "msg",
    "email"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "msg": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,}$"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the regex `.` still have matched the literal `.` in the string, though?

Comment: @Ether yes, but this isn't the case here. Here the single `\` results in an invalid json schema. I've edited my answer to make that more clear.